# How do I make my rotated span fit my div?

Tags: html, css

I couldn't think of a better title since I don't really know how to describe what I want. The desired effect is for the rotated txt in the white box to fill the blue area (it's blue just to illustrate what I want).

[image: Here is a screenshot]

I'm using bootstrap so I want to do this in a way that doesn't conflict with the current grid system layout. I'm new to css and programming in general so I don't know if one property in an unrelated style could cause/relieve my problem. To keep the post legible I will only include what I think is necessary.

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  background: url(C:/Users/user/Desktop/Programming/CSSzen/assets/images/onestones.jpg);
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 16px;
  .example {
    width: 90%;
  }
  .container {
    padding: 3%;
    margin: none;
  }
  .blockcontainer {
    width: 45%;
    min-width: 450px;
    text-align: justify;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 4%;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  .imagecontainer {
    width: 45%;
    min-width: 450px;
    text-align: justify;
    padding: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  .rotate {
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    position: absolute;
    width: 10vh;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(+90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(+90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(+90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(+90deg);
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
    -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  }
```

```html
<div class="row container">
  <div id="firstblock" class="blockcontainer col-sm-6">

    <--!There was some text within this div which I removed as it was too long-->

  </div>
  <div class="imagecontainer col-sm-6">
    <img class="example" src="C:/Users/user/Desktop/Programming/CSSzen/assets/imagessteel.png">
    <span class=" rotate">  
                        <p>Steel by Steffen Knoeller</p>
                    </span>
  </div>
</div>
<--!the container div is throughout the whole document so the closing tag is a long way down the code>
```

Just to reiterate, I'm new to this so I'm not sure if I included all the necessary information here.

Comment: If you don't mind some of the text being cut off, you could go with overflow hidden (with text-overflow: ellipsis; maybe).Or you could reduce the font size/line height.

Comment: Hi I checked your codes.Given codes not sufficient,please give global source of images.

Comment: @iyyappan I changed the src on the img tag if that's what you mean.